# What is ModelingProject used for in VS2010

Tags: c++, uml

I saw ModelingProject in vs2010. I created UMLClassDiagram. But how can this help us in coding. Can this be converted to c++ code?

Answer (score 0):

The major reason for UML diagrams is to plan your program before coding, because in large projects, diagrams are easier to understand / overview, and you could see conceptual errors before you write any code (else, you would be wasting time to write this first before you realize there is a problem).

And yes, with the right tools, you can generate parts of the code out of UML, like the structure of your classes, method/variable names etc., and then you fill in the "content" of the methods manually. It generates not much compared to the whole coding work, but better than nothing